# Render 3D objects

Tags: 3d, rendering, render, 3dsmax, 3d-modelling

I am a novice when it comes to 3D modeling and rendering and stuff. Now I have following question:

As far as I am concerned rendering a 3D model is only taking a realistic picture of the model (creating an image).

Now, what do I need to do/learn if I want to render a 3D object so I can use it in a 3D game? Am I right, that I could not use a renderer for my issue because rendering only means "creating an image"?

Comment: This is far too broad for a Stackoverflow question; this site was made to help users with *specific* programming problems. Nevertheless, to start with you may want to look at (a non-exhaustive list) -- 1) linear algebra and basic vector geometry; 2) view and projection matrices; 3) beginner's OpenGL/DirectX tutorials, including how to set up rendering contexts/devices for your target platform; 4) the rendering pipeline and the basic algorithms used, e.g. frustum clipping and depth buffering; 5) (optional) software rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is the object that was created in the 3d program is 'modelled' in 3d and then textured. Once this has occurred you can simply export the 'model' into any game engine using either .obj or .fbx format this is simply saving the model to the correct type, some might require Y-Up or Z-Up depending on the 3d engine. There is no rendering to occur when going to a 3d engine however you will probably 'bake' light sources on the textures, thereby creating a 'baked texture map'